# How change class of a C++ object (implementing a variadic type)

Tags: c++, programming-languages, interpreter, variant

*First off: I know that it is generally a bad idea to change an object's class, but I'm implementing my own programming language, and it has variables that can contain values of any type, and even change their type at will, so please assume I'm not a beginner not understanding OO basics.*

Currently, I implement my variant variables in C. Each one has a pointer to a table of function pointers, containing functions like `SetAsInt()`, `SetAsString()` etc., followed by what would be instance variables in C++. All objects are the same size.

When a variable contains a string and someone assigns an Int to it, I manually call the destructor, change the table of function pointers to point to the table used for variadic int values, and *then* set its int instance variable.

This is a bit hard to maintain, as every time I add a new type, I have to add a new table of function pointers and fill out *all* the function pointers in it. Structs of function pointers seem to be very badly type-checked, and missing fields don't lead to complaints, so I can easily accidentally forget one pointer in the list and get interesting crashes. Also, I have to repeat all the function pointers that are the same in most types.

I'd like to implement my variadic types in C++ instead, where a lot of this type-checking and inheriting default behaviours is done for me by the compiler. Is there a safe way to do this?

*PS - I know I could create a wrapper object and use `new` to allocate a new object, but I can't have the additional extra allocation overhead for every `int` variable on the stack.*

*PPS - The code needs to be portable across Linux, Mac, iOS and Windows for now, but if someone has a standard C++ solution, that would be even better.*

*PPPS - The list of types is extensible, but predetermined at compile-time. The base layer of my language defines just the basic types, but the host application my language is compiled into adds a few more types.*

#### Usage Example:

```
CppVariant someNum(42); // Creates it as CppVariantInt.

cout << "Original int: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
    << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl;

someNum->SetAsInt(700); // This is just a setter call.

cout << "Changed int: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
    << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl;

someNum->SetAsDouble(12.34); // This calls destructor on CppVariantInt and constructor on CppVariantDouble(12.34).

cout << "Converted to Double: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
    << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl; // GetAsInt() on a CppVariantDouble() rounds, or whatever.
```

(Imagine that beyond double and int, there would be other types in the future, like strings or booleans, but the caller of GetAsInt()/SetAsInt() shouldn't have to know what it is stored as, as long as it can be converted at runtime)

Comment: Have you looked at `boost::variant`?

Comment: Or [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oh, also, it seems I can't do .GetAsInt() on a std:: variant and it would pick the right class to call that method on, can I? It seems I have to say std::get<ConcreteSubclass>() for it to work, don't I?

Comment: Can you show how do you intend to use such a class? Maybe type-erasure can work for you, but I'm not that sure.

Comment: @skypjack Added an example to the question.

Comment: @uliwitness Added a possible implementation. Not sure it works fine for you, but give it a try. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a lark, I tried using *placement new* to do this, and I have ... something ... It compiles, it does the job, but I'm not sure if it's an improvement over pure C. Since I can't have a union of C++ objects, I create a `CPPVMAX()` macro to pass the largest `sizeof()` of all subclasses as the size to `mBuf[]`, but that's not really pretty either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#define CPPVMAX2(a,b)       (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define CPPVMAX3(a,b,c)     CPPVMAX2((a),CPPVMAX2((b),(c)))

using namespace std;


class CppVariantBase
{
public:
    CppVariantBase() { cout << "CppVariantBase constructor." << endl;  }
    virtual ~CppVariantBase() { cout << "CppVariantBase destructor." << endl; }

    virtual int     GetAsInt() = 0;
    virtual double  GetAsDouble() = 0;

    virtual void    SetAsInt( int n );
    virtual void    SetAsDouble( double n );
};


class CppVariantInt : public CppVariantBase
{
public:
    CppVariantInt( int n = 0 ) : mInt(n)
    {
        cout << "CppVariantInt constructor." << endl;
    }
    ~CppVariantInt() { cout << "CppVariantInt destructor." << endl; }

    virtual int     GetAsInt()      { return mInt; }
    virtual double  GetAsDouble()   { return mInt; }

    virtual void    SetAsInt( int n )           { mInt = n; }

protected:
    int     mInt;
};


class CppVariantDouble : public CppVariantBase
{
public:
    CppVariantDouble( double n = 0 ) : mDouble(n)
    {
        cout << "CppVariantDouble constructor." << endl;
    }
    ~CppVariantDouble()
    {
        cout << "CppVariantDouble destructor." << endl;
    }

    virtual int     GetAsInt()
    {
        if( int(mDouble) == mDouble )
            return mDouble;
        else
            return round(mDouble);
    }
    virtual double  GetAsDouble()           { return mDouble; }

    virtual void    SetAsDouble( int n )    { mDouble = n; }

protected:
    double mDouble;
};


class CppVariant
{
public:
    CppVariant( int n = 0 ) { new (mBuf) CppVariantInt(n); }
    ~CppVariant()           { ((CppVariantBase*)mBuf)->~CppVariantBase(); }

    operator CppVariantBase* () { return (CppVariantBase*)mBuf; }
    CppVariantBase* operator -> () { return (CppVariantBase*)mBuf; }

protected:
    uint8_t mBuf[CPPVMAX3(sizeof(CppVariantBase),sizeof(CppVariantInt),sizeof(CppVariantDouble))];
};

void    CppVariantBase::SetAsInt( int n )
{
    this->~CppVariantBase();
    new (this) CppVariantInt(n);
}


void    CppVariantBase::SetAsDouble( double n )
{
    this->~CppVariantBase();
    new (this) CppVariantDouble(n);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CppVariant someNum(42);

    cout << "Original int: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
        << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl;

    someNum->SetAsInt(700); // This is just a setter call.

    cout << "Changed int: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
        << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl;

    someNum->SetAsDouble(12.34);    // This changes the class to CppVariantDouble.

    cout << "Converted to Double: " << someNum->GetAsInt()
        << " (" << someNum->GetAsDouble() << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on type-erasure, union and template specializations.
I'm not sure it fits your requirements.
Anyway, here is what it gets:

- Anything is placed on the dynamic storage
- No hierarchy required

You can easily improve it further to reduce the amount of code, but this aims to serve as a base point from which to start.

It follows a minimal, working example based on the intended use in the question:

```
#include<iostream>

class CppVariant {
    union var {
        var(): i{0} {}
        int i;
        double d;
    };

    using AsIntF = int(*)(var);
    using AsDoubleF = double(*)(var);

    template<typename From, typename To>
    static To protoAs(var);

public:
    CppVariant(int);
    CppVariant(double);

    int getAsInt();
    double getAsDouble();

    void setAsInt(int);
    void setAsDouble(double);

private:
    var data;
    AsIntF asInt;
    AsDoubleF asDouble;
 };

template<>
int CppVariant::protoAs<int, int>(var data) {
    return data.i;
}

template<>
int CppVariant::protoAs<double, int>(var data) {
    return int(data.d);
}

template<>
double CppVariant::protoAs<int, double>(var data) {
    return double(data.i);
}

template<>
double CppVariant::protoAs<double, double>(var data) {
    return data.d;
}

CppVariant::CppVariant(int i)
    : data{},
      asInt{&protoAs<int, int>},
      asDouble{&protoAs<int, double>}
{ data.i = i; }

CppVariant::CppVariant(double d)
    : data{},
      asInt{&protoAs<double, int>},
      asDouble{&protoAs<double, double>}
{ data.d = d; }

int CppVariant::getAsInt() { return asInt(data); }
double CppVariant::getAsDouble() { return asDouble(data); }

void CppVariant::setAsInt(int i) {
    data.i = i;
    asInt = &protoAs<int, int>;
    asDouble = &protoAs<int, double>;
}

void CppVariant::setAsDouble(double d) {
    data.d = d;
    asInt = &protoAs<double, int>;
    asDouble = &protoAs<double, double>;
}

int main() {
    CppVariant someNum(42);
    std::cout << "Original int: " << someNum.getAsInt() << " (" << someNum.getAsDouble() << ")" << std::endl;
    someNum.setAsInt(700);
    std::cout << "Changed int: " << someNum.getAsInt() << " (" << someNum.getAsDouble() << ")" << std::endl;
    someNum.setAsDouble(12.34);
    std::cout << "Converted to Double: " << someNum.getAsInt() << " (" << someNum.getAsDouble() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hmm… this looks like it's basically the same as my original function-pointer-based C approach. And I actually *want* them to be different classes, as I have a number of data types (and plan to add more … hence the desire to move off C's brittle function pointers).

Comment: @uliwitness If you want them to be different classes with a common base, you cannot avoid using dynamic storage.

Comment: Sure can, at least with placement new (like in my "answer"). That's not a regular "new", that uses the buffer on the stack.